# Multiple Item Form Update with an image

Tags: image, ms-access

I am currently creating a multiple items form to show all the data I have, the interface will be similar to the one I have attached

[image]

This is in the design view. When I want to update the image for the selected record it updates the image for all records. Any suggestions on how I can update the image for each record individually? Or it is not possible to do it for multiple item form?
any other good suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For Ms Access 2007 and upwards:

The image control can be bound, you should set the `ControlSource` property of the image control to the field in the record source that contains the image path for each record.

For earlier versions of Ms Access (only works for single record forms):

You must set the image for each record in the `Form_Current` event.

Example function to be called (assuming the image control is called `imgPhoto`):

```
Public Sub SetPhoto(strPhotoPath As String)
    Screen.ActiveForm.imgPhoto.Picture = strPhotoPath 
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi E Mett, i have tried your method before. Sad to say, it doesnt work for me and i have no idea why.

Comment: Which method? Which version of Access are you using?

Comment: Hi E Mett, i'm currently using Office 2010. I have set the ControlSource property of the image control.